# Is it possible to filter Solr results using solrconfig.xml?

Tags: solr

I have a set of documents in Solr which I search through two different requestHandlers. One requestHandler is used internally and should be able to see all documents. The other is used by a public-facing search engine.

Is there a way I can apply an fq parameter in my requestHandler definition, so that a subset of the documents won't be returned?

In this instance I only want to return documents where the "fivi" field is NOT ZERO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [request handler wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) shows how to specify default values:

```
<requestHandler name="/foo" class="my.package.CustomRequestHandler" />
    <!-- initialization args may optionally be defined here -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="fl">*</str>
       <str name="version">2.1</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

But if you don't want them to be able to override the values then use `invariants` instead of `defaults` for the name of the `lst` element.

Comment: Thanks! Although in my case I will probably use `appends` rather than `invariants`, because I don't want to override the entire `fq` parameter, I would just like to make sure my `fq=-fivi:0` is in there.

Comment: Just adding this reference link here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration